# How to achieve horizontal scroll of cardviews using recyclerview in android

Tags: android, android-cardview

I want to achieve this kind of horizontal scroll of `CardViews` using `RecyclerView`. I know how to make horizontal scroll in `RecyclerView`. But I want to make the current item big compared to the other side items.

**Working video of the demo:**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/3aB9q.gif

**Static image of the behavior:**

[image]

How can I achieve the above behaviour ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe this helps you. SnapHelper with center snapping https://rubensousa.github.io/2016/08/recyclerviewsnap

Comment: tried it. but the current item which is at focus is of same size compared to other items. Please check the image for clarification.

Comment: There is an implementation with scaling views https://github.com/lauw/Android-SnappingRecyclerView

Comment: @Hiren does it help？